# Stop Spring MVC Fetch LazyLoad data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Created a simple spring boot project using `SpringBoot 1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` with `data-jpa` and `spring-mvc(web)` with 2 entities.

Parent entity

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Collection<Child> children;

    //Getter & Setter remove for brevity
}
```

Child entity

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Whenever an endpoint to fetch all `Parent` data is called, children data is also returned, yet, from my understanding by default fetchType is LazyLoading.

The following Spring Mvc rest code used to fetch data

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Parent>> findAll(HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(parents, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

What is expected and that is what should happen is only `Parent` data and not with Children data collection, should be fetched as they are lazyloaded.

How can i stop this undesired behavior of always eager loading children.

N.B: I tried setting `fetchType` to LazyLoad, though still when i call '/test', children data is also fetched

Comment: That has nothing to do with Hibernate, and everything to do with Jackson. You haven't told Jackson to ignore children when marshalling a parent to JSON; So it marshals the children, so Hibernate lazy-loads the children.

Comment: @JsonIgnore ...

Comment: You mean default behavior of Spring Mvc lets Jackson to fetch children?

Comment: @Snoob `@JsonIgnore` will not bring desired behavior as it will make children not to be marshalled forever. At certain point in the application children is needed

Comment: If you need to get the children, fetch it from the owning side (@ManyToOne), using @OneToMany is only good when your collection is small

Comment: The use DTOs, or Jackson views. The default behavior of Spring is to use Jackson to serialize objects. Jackson uses the standard Jackson rules. So if a field is not annotated with JsonIgnore, it will be marshalled.

Comment: Is there a way to configure Jackson not to serialize relations that are lazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed to stop `Jackson` from kindly pulling lazy-loaded data for me.

To do that just 
Add the following maven dependency

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
  </dependency>
```

Then subclass `ObjectMapper` like so and register hibernate module depending on the hibernate version you are using.I'm using Hibernate 5, so i did this

```
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
    }
}
```

Finally add a `Bean`

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    return new HibernateAwareObjectMapper();
}
```

With above code in-place, lazy-loaded attribute are not auto-initialized.